# It's a small word after all!

Tags: word, knowledge

[image]

Text version

> This <sub>noun</sub>
>
> Is a 10 letter word
>
> Which is also a 6 letter word
>
> Which is also a 2 letter word
>
> Which is also a single letter too!
>
> <sub>No abbreviations or acronyms.</sub>

Comment: Is "afterall" an intentional misspelling?

Comment: not really. It is shown both ways Afterall or after all. Not intentional. I will edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A single letter =

> μ (a Greek letter)

2 letter word =

> mu

6 letter word =

> micron

10 letter word =

> micrometer

A "small" word indeed.

Comment: Wonderfully done @Helix Quar. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

I got...

> 'Personally' which is a 10 letter word, which is a synonym for 'myself' which is a six-letter word which is a synonym for 'me' which is a two letter word which is a synonym for 'I' which is a one letter word.
>  But these are pronouns which I believe are a type of noun but I'm not sure if they count.

Comment: fznyy jbeq naq fznyy abha ner fvtavsvpnag pyhrf @Amoz